# How do I preview the description text in new ticket

Tags: jira

How do I preview what the ticket description will look like while entering a new ticket or editing an existing ticket?

The controls I see at the top of the description box are:
[image]

The controls I see at the bottom of the description box are:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try Visual editing.

As a JIRA administrator, you have to enable this feature in `System` > `User interface` > `rich text editor`.
This should provide two buttons at the bottom of the description field, that allow you to switch between `Text` and `Visual` mode.

[image: JIRA Entering Visual mode]

Entering Visual mode shows the preview you're looking for.

See [JIRA Core documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver072/visual-editing-838542506.html) for further details.